# rooting Smart Tv (Skyworth e69 6369)

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, smart-tv

I got a Skyworth e69 6369 smart tv.
kernel 3.1.10
android 4.2.1
model full aosp on skyworth 6369
cpu arm cortex a9 dual core
other specs http://specdevice.com/showspec.php?id=de85-dcab-0033-c5870033c587

It does not come with any data cable. It has 4 usb ports though I don't think I can use any for rooting.

I have tried several no pc solutions like framaroot 1.9.3, kingroot 3.4.1.157, poot, romastersu 2.0.3_140926_100, vroot 4.3, z4root 1.3.0 etc but not successful.

What is the best way to root this if any? Or is this sadly unrootable?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Did you try Towelroot?

Answer (score -1):

After a long time trying I managed to finally root it

In summary, I think these are the steps to make it work:

1. Try to root with rootmaster. Check if it gives you root. If it does- check if it persists on reboot. If it does not do 2 and 3.
2. Try to root again with rootmaster then delete `/system/app/kinguser`, `/system/app/superuser.apk`, and `/system/app/Superuser.apk` (using a terminal)
3. Install [SuperSu](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu)

Only thing missing from this smart TV that I want it to have is Google Play Store. I really cannot make it work. I also don't have YouTube because of this.